# Coluna com erro de caractere utf-8

Tags: sql-server, mysql

Ao executar:

```
SELECT campus_nome FROM cursosprounine where campus_nome like ('%?%')group by campus_nome;
```

para verificar o erro de caracteres, 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Encontrei um código que me ensinou a converter a coluna:

```
UPDATE cursosprounine 
   SET campus_nome = CONVERT(CONVERT(CONVERT(campus_nome USING latin1) USING binary) USING utf8);
```

mas observei que o erro continua em, VALPARAISO de GOI?S- Parque Esplanada III, sendo que o certo é "VALPARAISO DE GOIÁS"
na coluna de turno, utilizei o código:
update cursosprounine set turno = 'Curdo a Distância' where turno = 'Curdo a Dist?ncia' para corrigir o de turno que eram: Manhã, Tarde, Noite, Curso a Distância, como são poucos foi tranquilo, mas como esse de campus_nome, não consegui, ajuda?
p.s:corrigir o erro de latin1/utf-8

Comment: É MySQL ou SQL Server?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Tente isso:

`ALTER TABLE cursosprounine CHANGE COLUMN campus_nome campus_nome VARCHAR(500) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`